# Mutual Authentication for Custom Apex Rest Web Serivce

Tags: rest-api, integration

We are in the process of an integration between Salesforce and Pega systems.

Since the client wants the API connection to be more secure, we are using OAuth along with JWT tokens to authenticate with Salesforce.

After getting the access token, we would like to make the 2nd REST API using mutual authentication.

I saw in the Salesforce documentation that we should be using port number 8483 for mutual authentication, but the example given in the document is SOAP API. I would like to know if we should use the port number for making API Calls in REST API also.

For Example : `https://na8.salesforce.com:8483/services/apexrest/FieldCase?companyName=GenePoint?`

Can someone please help with the steps for mutual authentication using Rest API?